# Deleted Ubuntu partition now cannot get past Grub Rescue

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I deleted my Ubuntu partition from Windows 7, and when I boot my computer it says:

**error: unknown file system
Entering rescue mode...
Grub rescue>**

Now I can enter commands.

I googled a lot of different things but can't find an answer. I've entered `ls`, and got a list of all the partitions. From there I tried to `ls` all three partitions listed. Every time it says File system unknown.

I've tried starting my computer with a windows install disk in it and it goes to grub rescue anyways.

I have also tried to boot from a usb containing Ubuntu and on a separate occasion from one with windows 7. Both times I just got a blinking underscore and nothing else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a windows 7/8/10 disc or bootable usb.

Boot from windows boot media. Select your language and press next.

Then click on `repair your computer` option in bottom left.

Now depending on which windows disc you have, you need to find the `command promt` option in `repair your computer` menu. It is usually under advanced options.

Once you get yourself in command prompt, simply type these 2 commands.

1 : `bootrec /fixmbr` and press enter.

2 : `bootrec /fixboot` and press enter.

Exit out of command prompt by typing `exit`. Then turn off your system and restart.

You should now be booting in Windows 7.